# Oracle 11g memory leak in Win 2008?

Tags: oracle, memory-leaks, oracle10g, oracle11g

So we have an instance of Oracle 11g running off a Win 2008 R2 server.  Although I know Oracle and Microsoft might not get along too well, it gets to the point where Oracle is eating up about 50% of the ram on the box, and never releases it, so from time to time, I bounce the service just to flush it out.  I've been trying to find whether or not there's an alternative to releasing this memory somehow without having to bounce the service, but so far no luck.

Has anyone else encountered this and found a way to flush that memory through alternative means?   Any input would be appreciated!

Here are the current allocations from spfile / parameters on this instance... If you have any suggested setup based on available memory, just let me know what you need and I can provide additional information. Thanks so much for your input on this.

```
archive_lag_target                   integer  0
db_flashback_retention_target        integer  1440
fast_start_io_target                 integer  0
fast_start_mttr_target               integer  0
memory_max_target                    integer  10368319488
memory_target                        integer  10368319488
parallel_servers_target              integer  64
pga_aggregate_target                 integer  0
sga_target                           integer  0
```

Answer (score 10):

Are you sure that this is a leak rather than the SGA Oracle is configured to use?

In general, regardless of platform, Oracle is going to allocate a large chunk of memory at startup for the SGA (System Global Area).  This is what the database uses for things like caching blocks in RAM, caching SQL statements, etc.  Every time a session is created, Oracle will allocate a much smaller chunk of memory for the PGA (Program Global Area) of that session.  That's memory for things like sorts and hashing that will grow and shrink as the session requires it.  It wouldn't be unusual to configure Oracle to use half a machine's physical RAM as SGA and 15-20% of the physical RAM for total PGA leaving the remainder for the operating system and other applications.  You should be able to dial that memory usage down though that may cause performance issues as more I/O requires physical reads rather than being satisfied from cache.

Your configuration settings are instructing Oracle to use up to 9.65 GB of RAM between SGA and PGA and to allocate that memory as it sees fit.  It would be entirely reasonable to expect Oracle to grab 6 or 7 GB of RAM at startup for the SGA and to keep that RAM allocated forever.  And that under load, Oracle would likely have in the neighborhood of 9.65 GB of RAM allocated between the shared SGA and the session-level PGAs.  Is that the behavior that you're seeing?  If so, it sounds like Oracle is behaving as expected, that there is no memory leak, and that there is no need to restart the service.

Comment: +1, as always a good answer from Justin. Burleson's site has a nice brief on the topic: http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle11g/oracle_11g_memory_target_parameter.htm

Comment: SGA should be 'grabbed' at startup. PGA will be grabbed by a process as and when needed. The process might release it, or it might hold on to it until the process terminates (eg session logs out). If your app uses a connection pool, and doesn't end its sessions, that might have this effect.